# use get_sites subsite_id with get_bloginfo"() and/or get_custom_logo

Tags: multisite

I inadvertently posted a duplicate of this question in the other stackexchange - but it was MISTAKENLY marked as duplicated and solved by a different question answered using deprecated code

So I will reask in the Wordpress forum where there may be more expertise

I'm trying to combine functions - and don't know how it is done

I'm successfully using get_sites to produce a list of WP Multisite subsites.

I'm hoping to also pull get_custom_logo to display the logo, and get_bloginfo for things like $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );

just don't know how to merge the gets. this is working

```
/** get sites */
function make_list_shortcode() {
$subsites = get_sites(
[
'public'  => 1,
'number'  => 500,
'orderby' => 'last_updated',
'order'   => 'DESC',
]
);
if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {
$html = '<ul class="icon-bullets-greater">';
foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {
$subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id;
$subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
$subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
$subsite_domain = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->domain;
$subsite_path = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->path;
$html .= '<li style="list-style: none!important;" class="site-' . 
$subsite_id . '" ><a href="' . $subsite_link . '" target="_blank">' . 
$subsite_name . '</a> at ' . $subsite_domain . '' . $subsite_path . ' </li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
return $html;
}
}
add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

modifying to this, works thanks

// Switch to Blog
            switch_to_blog( $subsite->blog_id );
            $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
            restore_current_blog();

still working on calling the logos

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the theme you are using on multi-site is supporting the Theme Logo feature. Then you could simply use **get_theme_mod('custom_logo')**. Please note that the **custom_logo** is named by the theme developer, some themes may be different than others.

```
<?php
/** get sites */

function make_list_shortcode()
    {
    $subsites = get_sites(['public' => 1, 'number' => 500, 'orderby' => 'last_updated', 'order' => 'DESC', ]);
    if (!empty($subsites))
        {
        $html = '<ul class="icon-bullets-greater">';
        foreach($subsites as $subsite)
            {
            $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id;
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->siteurl;
            $subsite_domain = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->domain;
            $subsite_path = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->path;

            // Switch to Blog
            switch_to_blog( $subsite->blog_id );
            $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
            $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );

            // Added the image tag and src path
            $html.= '<li style="list-style: none!important;" class="site-' . $subsite_id . '" ><img src="'.$logo.'" /><a href="' . $subsite_link . '" target="_blank">' . $subsite_name . '</a> at ' . $subsite_domain . '' . $subsite_path . ' </li>';
            }

        $html.= '</ul>';
        return $html;
        }
    }

add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

Comment: thanks -- the switch_to_blog is breaking the layout no matter what I try there --- I'm wondering if   restore_current_blog();  is required, but I can't figure out how/where to implement that